# LightningComponentBundle "Not available for deploy for this API version" error

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, vs-code, cli

I receive a strange error "Not available for deploy for this API version" for deploying LightningComponentBundle by sfdx force:source:deploy command or by VS Code Menu Item "SFDX Deploy Source To Org".

> 21:55:35.494 sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath
>   d:\Reps\testname\salesforce\FLSMan\force-app\main\default\lwc\fls
>   --json --loglevel fatal {"message":"Deploy failed.","status":1,"stack":"DeployFailed: Deploy failed.\n    at
>   ALMError (C:\Program Files\Salesforce
>   CLI\client\node_modules\salesforce-alm\dist\lib\almError.js:44:19)\n
>   at MetadataRegistry.initializeMetadataTypeInfos.then.catch.e
>   (C:\Program Files\Salesforce
>   CLI\client\node_modules\salesforce-alm\dist\lib\source\sourceApiCommand.js:67:35)\n
>   at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\Salesforce
>   CLI\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)\n
>   at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\Salesforce
>   CLI\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:510:31)\n
>   at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\Salesforce
>   CLI\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:567:18)\n
>   at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\Salesforce
>   CLI\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:612:10)\n
>   at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\Salesforce
>   CLI\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:687:18)\n
>   at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\Salesforce
>   CLI\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:16)\n
>   at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\Salesforce
>   CLI\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:148:10)\n
>   at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Program Files\Salesforce
>   CLI\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)\n
>   at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)\n    at tryOnImmediate
>   (timers.js:751:5)\n    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback]
>   (timers.js:722:5)","name":"DeployFailed","result":[{"error":"Not
>   available for deploy for this API
>   version","type":"LightningComponentBundle","filePath":"N/A"},{"error":"Not
>   available for deploy for this API
>   version","type":"LightningComponentBundle","filePath":"N/A"},{"error":"Not
>   available for deploy for this API
>   version","type":"LightningComponentBundle","filePath":"N/A"}],"warnings":["All
>   --json output, including on error, is moving to stdout. Use the SFDX_JSON_TO_STDOUT environment variable to move over to the new
>   functionality. This will become the default in version 45."]}
>   21:55:42.432 sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath
>   d:\Reps\testname\salesforce\IronMan\force-app\main\default\lwc\fls
>   --json --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 1

[image]

I use the newest version of VS Code and the newest version of Salesforce Extension Pack and I have updated Salesforce CLI and even reinstalled it but still receive the same error.

This is very confusing since when I convert the source to MDAPI format and deploy it with `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d src` command it works just fine!

Also definitely the org I am using is on version 45, since I was able to deploy LWC by mdapi:deploy command.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like I have found already a culprit here.
It is very important to check `sourceApiVersion` property of [project.json configuration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm).

Looks like this value was `44.0` in my project. Probably because I have created it before updating the salesforce-cli tool. Then I updated the CLI and even reinstalled it but the project version has not been changed.

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": /*"44.0"=>*/"45.0"
}
```

Now after updating this configuration settings, it started working successfully.

Comment: in my case, it was package.xml with an older version. After updating work properly.

Comment: Seems like for some metadata (Flows), salesforce doesn't respect the specified API version at all, and just uses the latest version.